# How to implement IAP (in application programming) for STM23F107 ARM microcontroller?

Tags: arm, bootloader, stm32

I want to design a board with STM32F107 (or other STM32F microcontrollers) with the capability of **IAP** from *SD card*, *USB*, and a *serial flash* (like AT45DB161)

- In the following paragraph, I'll try to describe my solution. ***Please correct me if I am wrong.***

As I know ([STM32F107 datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00220364.pdf), section 2.3.8), STM32F107 can boot from **system memory**, **SRAM**, or **user flash** based on BOOT pines settings (BOOT0, and BOOT1[PB7]).

According to "*STM32 microcontroller system memory boot mode*" document ([STM32 Application note AN2606](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00167594.pdf) page 55, Fig. 15), the ROM bootloader of STM32 checks USB, USART, and CAN buses for signal availability, and goes on ... (system memory boot mode is activated when "BOOT1_BOOT0 = 01").

Therefore when I want to program my STM32 using USB port (not a USB stick), I must set boot pins to "BOOT1_BOOT0 = 01" and connect a usb programmer to the board and ... (and this operation is a kind of ISP -in system programming- method, ***is'nt it?***)

However, to be able to program my STM32 from a USB stick or an SD card, I think STM32 must first boot from *user flash* (a custom bootloader program), check a flag (say, a byte in flash memory) to see if it should check the disk file system (USB stick or SD card) or serial flash for a new version of firmware.

- If **YES**, it will again check if the new firmware is going to upgrade **the custom bootloader itself** or **the application**: (1) if the target is the custom bootloader, it must first copy the bootloader to SRAM and then run it; or (2) if the application is the target, it must start the upgrading process.
- If **NO**, it must jump to the application.

***I would appreciate any comments and suggestions.***

Comment: There was no question :P Your idea sounds sane. You could also use multiple flash areas that are upgraded separately, so you prevent problems when there's power outage during upgrade, and your working code is only in SRAM.

Comment: Dear SzybkiSasza, you are completely right. I have no direct question. Actually, I am newbie to bootloader things. I just spent a few hours on studying the subject. And I was wondering if I had understood it correctly. Thank you for your comment. It really helps.

Comment: in application programming means exactly that the application running on the microcontroller can program the flash on that chip...So absolutely you can write an application or bootloader that can program the on board flash from whatever on or off board resource you like.  Just write that program.

Comment: Independently of that there happens to be an on board bootloader as well, which only does what it is defined to do, it has a limited number of host to target interfaces that you can use basically to program the on board flash, I cant imagine they would provide features on a platform like this to allow you to plug in something other than a host usb, i2c, uart or spi where the mcu is the slave/target (not one where it is the master).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to write your own bootloader, you can use any of the gpio pins (not the boot pins) as the strap pins to YOUR bootloader (in the way the boot pins are straps to the st bootloader) to tell your bootloader how to boot or where to look for things.  Then based on that decision your bootloader either boots the application from somewhere in user flash or accesses some attached media or goes into a mode waiting on a host to download through some interface.

Whether or not you have to copy the data to sram to then burn to flash or not depends on the flash interface design, there may be a page sized buffer you just write into.  It is quite likely that your implementation will want to use sram as a store and forward anyway, say extracting data off of an external device using the sram to store data in units of size from that device.   then writing to flash using units of size required for the flash peripheral.

The boot pins determine whether or not the user flash is used or an ST bootloader flash is used.  The ST bootloader listens on one or more interfaces (usb, uart, spi, i2c, whatever they support), as a slave to some master than can then program the user flash.  So long as your board design is such that the boot pins needed and the interface is left available this option is always there, but the moving of the data to be programmed is done by an external master, the actual programming of the flash from that data is done by the bootloader.  You can also implement one of these yourself, within your bootloader scheme.

You can for your own bootloader use straps, gpio pins, or sure you could have some data in a flash that drives the boot process, this is similar to how a computer boots or uboot works, where say on your computer running linux you have grub with a configuration in non-volatile storage (the hard disk for example) that drives the default boot, once booted that non-volatile storage can be changed.   u-boot there is some flash somewhere that contains system environment variables some of which are the boot parameters, once booted, or if you stop in u-boot that is on a console you can change those boot parameters for the next boot.  gpio straps are like the boot pins for st's bootloader, you define as many pins as required for the different options, strap them/short them high or low to pick a combination that matches the desired boot, to change the boot option instead of flashing something you change the straps.  You could for example have some sort of presence detect on an sd card slot if present then boot from that otherwise boot from elsewhere.  In that case you dont have to actually write the program from the sd card to flash to run it if you have enough resources you can copy it to ram and run it from ram.  Which is true for any of the boot options you choose, you can burn them to flash and then run from there or you can just copy to ram, depends on how large the programs are and if you want to have a way to use them on another power cycle and not have to read from the media.

In short you can pretty much do whatever you want so long as you have enough resources (interfaces and storage (volatile and non-volatile).  No that doesnt mean you can directly execute from an sd card, but it does mean you can pull the program from an sd card then execute, or pull a portion of it from the sd card, execute that, the pull some more in an overlay fashion.

Comment: You're one of the the best, old_timer